# How to get value from previous field to new field

Tags: sql

Is there any way to call value from previous field to the new field by using trigger?
i have tried with following method and this method is working perfectly with first row but when i moved to second row it automatically copy data from "remaining" to "monthly" field:

```
BEGIN
IF (:REMAINING IS NULL) THEN
:REMAINING=:MONTHLY-:FEE;
NEXT_ITEM;
:MONTHLY:=:REMAINING;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: your question is not clear,please provide sample data and expected output as text and also tag the dbms you are using

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at Excel or similar.